# Middle arrow for dynkin diagrams

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, dynkin-diagrams

I want something like this for my Dynkin diagrams:

[image]

What I'm not able to create is the middle arrowhead. Up until now I managed to obtain this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\underset{1}{\bullet}
\arrow[shorten <= -6pt, shorten >= -6pt, no head, r]
& \underset{2}{\bullet}
\arrow[shorten <= -6pt, shorten >= -6pt, no head, r]
& \underset{3}{\bullet}
&[-22pt] \dots
&[-25pt] \underset{n-1}{\bullet}
\arrow[shorten <= -12pt, shorten >= -7pt, shift right=0.5, no head, r]
\arrow[shorten <= -12pt, shorten >= -7pt, shift left=0.6, no head, r]
& \underset{n}{\bullet}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

which gives me this:
[image]
How can I obtain (only one) arrow head in the middle of the two arrows which connect the last two nodes?

EDIT: I am really grateful to @Qrrbrbirlbel, he/she devoted a lot of time to my problem, but in the end I used the dynkin diagrams package, so I accepted the other answer.

Comment: `decorations.markings` library: [Q3161](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161) or a [custom pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688976).

Comment: If you are not happy with the dynkin-diagrams package (https://ctan.org/pkg/dynkin-diagrams), please let me know what you would like to be done differently.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Is there a way to reduce the angle on the last two edges of the diagram D_n? Also, are there more styles for the indefinite edges?

Comment: On page 4 of the dynkin-diagrams manual you can find ways to customize the `indefinite edge`. As for changing the angle, I can only offer a cheat: `\begin{dynkinDiagram}[edge length=1cm,root radius=3pt,
    labels={1,2,n-1,n},/tikz/yscale=0.5,*/.append style={yscale=2}]D{**.***}
\end{dynkinDiagram}`. Anyway, these are just some minor remarks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a wonderful, tizkz-based package for Dynkin diagrams: `dynkin-diagrams`. The diagrams are highly customizable, and the manual is very well written. The diagram you are after can be obtained very straightforwardly.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[edge length=1cm,root radius=3pt,
    labels={1,2,n-1,n}]B{**.**}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The arrow in the middle is placed via the `arrow` pic, alternatively you can use the [`decorations.markings` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161).

We can setup `tikzcd` in a way that places a bullet at each cell.
We will use labels via the `quotes` library to place the numbers below the bullets. The `\mathstrut` in the setup makes it so that all those nodes have the same height/depth which will align them better.

The `dots` key can be used to place dots instead of a normal line.

The `dbl` key uses the `nfold` library and the same `1.2ex` as the `every bullet` style to draw two parallel lines.

The `mid arrow` uses the `arrow` pic to place an arrow tip halfway along the arrow. Use `<` to reverse the direction.

Three parallel lines are drawn by a combination of `dbl` and a normal arrow. (This could be improved but it's the easiest to do.)

If this is needed more and especially for curved paths, we will need another solution (`nfold = 3`) but we might want to make sure the middle line won't be drawn over the dots in case you want to use different colors for bullets and arrows.

Using `between origins` with the column and row separator helps align the dots in a properly grid without the labels messing it up.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, nfold, quotes}
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\tikzcdset{
  dynkin/.style={
    every matrix/.append style={
      row sep={2em,between origins}, column sep={2.5em,between origins}},
    arrows={dash, thick},
    dots/.style={
      path only,
      /tikz/every to/.append style={
        edge node={node[%
          commutative diagrams/every label, font=, auto=false, sloped]{$\cdots$}}}},
    dbl/.style={
      start anchor=center, end anchor=center,
      double distance between line centers=+1.2ex, nfold=2},
    mid arrow/.default=,
    mid arrow/.style={
      /tikz/every to/.append style={edge node={
        pic[{sloped, allow upside down,</.style={xscale=-1},##1}]
          {arrow={Straight Barb[angle'=120]}}}}},
    cells={nodes={circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1.2ex, draw, fill, thick}},
    /tikz/label position=below,
    /tikz/every label/.style={
      commutative diagrams/every label, shape=rectangle,
       execute at begin node=\mathstrut, path only}}}
\tikzcdset{label dynkin/.style 2 args={execute at end picture={
  \node[xshift=-.6666em,left,text depth=+0pt]at(\tikzcdmatrixname-#1.west){$#2$};}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={1-1}{A_n, n>0}]
|["1"]| \ar[r] & |["2"]| \ar[r] & |["3"]| \ar[r, dots] & |["n-1"]| \ar[r] & |["n"]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={1-1}{B_n, n>1}]
|["1"]| \ar[r] & |["2"]| \ar[r] & |["3"]| \ar[r, dots]
 & |["n-1"]| \ar[r, dbl, mid arrow] & |["n"]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={1-1}{C_n, n>2}]
|["1"]| \ar[r] & |["2"]| \ar[r] & |["3"]| \ar[r, dots]
 & |["n-1"]| \ar[r, dbl, mid arrow=<] & |["n"]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={2-1}{D_n, n>3}, row sep=tiny]
 & & & & & |["n'" right]| \\
 |["1"]| \ar[r] & |["2"]| \ar[r] & |["3"]| \ar[r, dots]
 & |["n-1"]| \ar[r] & |["n"]| \ar[ur] \ar[dr] \\
 & & & & & |["n^*" right]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={2-1}{E_6}]
 & & |["3'" above]| \\
 |["1"]| \ar[r] & |["2"]| \ar[r] & |["3"]| \ar[r] \ar[u]
 & |["4"]| \ar[r] & |["5"]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={2-1}{E_7}]
 & & |["3'" above]| \\
 |["1"]| \ar[r] & |["2"]| \ar[r] & |["3"]| \ar[r] \ar[u]
 & |["4"]| \ar[r] & |["5"]| \ar[r] & |["6"]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={2-1}{E_8}]
 & & |["3'" above]| \\
 |["1"]| \ar[r] & |["2"]| \ar[r] & |["3"]| \ar[r] \ar[u]
 & |["4"]| \ar[r] & |["5"]| \ar[r] & |["6"]| \ar[r] & |["7"]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={1-1}{F_4}]
 |["1"]| \ar[r] & |["2"]| \ar[r, dbl, mid arrow] & |["3"]| \ar[r] & |["4"]|
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[dynkin, label dynkin={1-1}{G_2}]
 |["1"]| \ar[r] \ar[r, dbl, mid arrow] & |["2"]|
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is (almost) perfect. The only two things I'd like to change are: 1) I want the nodes to be full and 2) in the example with three lines the center one doesn't touch B. How can I fix this?

Comment: just one more thing: overleaf says that "Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'nfold'. I looked for files named tikzlibrarynfold.code.tex and pgflibrarynfold.code.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf trees.."

Comment: also, I would really like the lines to be tangent to the bullets in the example with three lines. Would that be possible to implement?

Comment: Judging by the picture it looks like the lines connecting A and B are not touching the bullet on the "edge". I would like them to intersect opposite endpoints of a diameter. And what do you mean by implementing it myself? Can I implement it on overleaf? By the way thanks a lot, you are really helpful :)

Comment: ok, I found a way to add it to overleaf. Thanks a lot! Just one last thing: what if I want the arrow to point left? I tried putting "l" instead of "r" but to no avail.

Comment: Again a problem: when typesetting the diagrams E6, E7, E8, the number of the upper node intersects its arrow (e.g. \begin{tikzcd}[dynkin]
    & & 3 \ar[d] & & & \\
1 \ar[r]
 & 2 \ar[r]
   & 3 \ar[r, dots]
     & n-1 \ar[r, dbl, mid arrow]
       & n
\end{tikzcd} )

Comment: @toyr99 My previous attempt is much better even if it means adding `|["` and `"]|` around the labels. But once you get the hang for it (or paste it from your clipboard) it's a much better solution without reinventing the wheel.